# When I tried to build my solution using MSBuild, its launches Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to build a solution using MSBUILD. Instead of building the solution, it launches the Visual Studio.

```
E:\MyProject> <path to MSBuild>\msbuild.exe MySolution.sln
```

I am calling the Msbuild step from the Jenkins and due to the above issue it is getting stuck.
Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: [devenv.exe /Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)

Comment: This should definitely work. Which MSBuild version?

Answer (score 2):

> When I tried to build my solution using MSBuild, its launches Visual
> Studio

**Usually**, VS IDE will start only when `devenv.exe` is called.

**First**, please check every `proj` file under the solution folder and make sure that there is no such bat file or command to  call `denenv.exe` in `proj` file.

enter every `xxx.csproj` or `xxx.vcxproj` file, check if there is something similar to the following:

```
    <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
        <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe&quot;&#xD;&#xA; &#xD;&#xA;" />
      </Target>
    
      <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
        <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe&quot;&#xD;&#xA;" />
      </Target>

   <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
  Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**If so**, you should delete them and make them not call **devenv**. **devenv** will start VS IDE.

**Second**, you should call msbuild version like:

MSBuild of VS2017:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

MSBuild of VS2019:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Use MSBuild Command Line on **Jenkins** like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe xxx\MySolution.sln /t:build
```

**Besides**, you can also check whether Jenkins has a job to call `devenv`. If so, you should remove it.

Comment: Executing this alone `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`   opens Visual Studio. There is also no devenv in any of the proj file.

Comment: Quite strange and it will not execute VS IDE in my side. Please try to [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or disable any third party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions` to check whether some extensions cause this situation.